# Grails. Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'

Tags: grails, grails-controller

I'm getting started with Grails (3.x) Framework but I got stuck with this error while trying to render domain content to a view:

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error
URI /hello/index
Class javax.servlet.ServletException
Message: Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
```

HelloController.groovy:

```
package helloworld   
class HelloController {

    def index() {
        def Person persona1 = new Person(firstName: "someone", lastName: "stuck", age: 21)
        [persona:persona1]
    }
}
```

Person.groovy:

```
package helloworld

class Person {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    int age
}
```

Comment: you should be able to run something like `grails generate-views ..` to generate the views.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure that `grails-app/views/hello/index.gsp` file exists.

Comment: This is not the proper solution. Its problem related redirect of file regarding view and model.

Answer (score 7):

I know that this has an answer, but I thought I'd chime in that I am using Grails 3.0.11 and I found that somethings code like the following will work

```
render(view: 'index', model: [data: value])
```

Where as the following will fail with the error above.

```
def index() {
    [data:value]
}
```

If I have time, I will poke around more with this and attempt to understand what's going on.

Comment: This worked for me with gson views.  Does anyone know why just returning the model map doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

if you're using GNU/Linux, check the folder name, files, etc. for case inconsistency.

```
grails-app/views/Hello/index.gsp
grails-app/views/hello/index.gsp <-- Not the same
```

GNU/Linux is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

[grails generate-views](http://docs.grails.org/3.3.5/ref/Command%20Line/generate-views.html) - generates GSP views for the given domain class